# An [exhaustive] list of reasons why this tag is superfluous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just came about the [exhaustive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exhaustive) tag. It has no description and a total of 14 questions. Among those, the obvious confusion took place.  People have used the tag for the following kind of questions:

- algorithmic questions about *exhaustive search*
- questions about *memory exhaustion*
- arbitrary other questions

My proposal is to remove the tag from all of those questions, re-tagging the first group of questions with [brute-force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brute-force) and the second with [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory) if those tags are not already used. I don't think that any valuable information would be lost this way.

The term is too generic to be applied consistently so I think the tag cannot be fixed and should simply go altogether.

I can easily do the suggested cleanup myself should there be no objections.

Comment: "I can easily do the suggested cleanup myself should there be no objections." Are you sure? It seems like an ... exhaustive ... task.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I see what you did there [ಠ_ಠ](https://media.giphy.com/media/AmxzmH9szFkqY/giphy.gif)

Comment: @Braiam: And I'm still not sorry. ;)

Comment: @pnuts [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312879/r-regex-output-change-all-occurrences-after-particular-letter) just so happens to include the word “exhaustive” and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239232/faulty-base-case-haskell) I have no idea why the tag was applied.

Comment: Can we please stop with the tag cleanup puns already?

Comment: "memory" is another great tag...

Comment: @Lundin I've cleaned up the remaining questions in [tag:exhaustive]. There was only one memory exhaustion question left. Whats the process if the burnination is complete?

Comment: @Magisch If there are 0 questions marked with the tag, the site will automatically delete the tag after a certain time has passed.

Comment: @immibis We would, but I don't think we've *exhuasted* the set of all puns.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I went ahead and purged the few remains of this tag off SO.

List of retagged Questions (for posterity):

**- Retagged to [brute-force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brute-force) (These pertain exhaustive search algorithms):**

- [How is Greedy Technique different from Exhaustive Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234521/how-is-greedy-technique-different-from-exhaustive-search)
- [Non exhaustive error in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402236/non-exhaustive-error-in-function)
- [minimax c++ implementation for tic tac toe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808074/minimax-c-implementation-for-tic-tac-toe-need-help)
- [How is regsubsets in R's leaps package optimized under the hood for exhaustive model selection searches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638049/how-is-regsubsets-in-rs-leaps-package-optimized-under-the-hood-for-exhaustive-m)
- [Mathematica- If statement not performing true/false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459003/mathematica-if-statement-not-performing-true-false)
- [N+1 queens algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086180/n1-queens-algorithm)
- [Matlab: cumsum and exhaustive unique element's indexing with greedy perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749475/matlab-cumsum-and-exhaustive-unique-elements-indexing-with-greedy-perspective)
- [Exhaustive Search Big-O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916925/exhaustive-search-big-o)
- [Algorithm for calculating definite integrals with bounds at infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701374/algorithm-for-calculating-definite-integrals-with-bounds-at-infinity)

**- Tag removed without replacement:**

- [Faulty base-case Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239232/faulty-base-case-haskell)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225570/weakness-of-half-of-des-x (also flagged for closure for unclear what you are asking)
- [PHP Memory exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534274/php-memory-exhausted) (about memory exhaustion, [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory) already present.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you for taking care of this. I was wondering how much time I should give this thread before I may feel comfortable taking action. Apparently, I was waiting too long. ;-)

Comment: @5gon12eder erring on the side of caution for burninate requests is always good, which is why I also provided the list of questions I retagged. But this was a low impact and pretty clear cut case.